# Never getting online azure SQL data using MobileServiceSQLiteStore

Tags: sqlite, azure, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use the MobileServiceSQLiteStore synchronisation but i'm never retrieving online stored data.

Actually, using the online mode is perfectly working. But when i use IMobileServiceSyncTable instead of IMobileServiceTable, the local store is never populated with online data even after push and pull operations.

There is a strange point, when I insert data via IMobileServiceSyncTable , my azure online data is populated, and this new data will be correctly read at the new app start in the local store.

Here is an exemple of my code :

```
//service client access
this.client = new MobileServiceClient(Constants.ApplicationURL);
//local store definition
this.Store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(offlineDbPath);

//intializing table in local store
Store.DefineTable<MYTABLE>();

//Initializing synchronisation context
await CurrentClient.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(Store);

//mapping table 
var myTable = CurrentClient.GetSyncTable<MYTABLE>();

//Full synchronisation
await client.SyncContext.PushAsync();
await myTable.PullAsync(null, myTable.CreateQuery());

//Getting results from local store 
var results = await myTable.ToListAsync();
```

So, at this point, results still empty. But i get all data using GetTable instead of GetSyncTable. 
To be more precise, I have 5 rows stored in my SQL Azure table interfaced using Azure EasyTables by an Azure AppService. 
If I use the following code, everything works fine, i succesfully get my 5 results :

```
//service client access
this.client = new MobileServiceClient(Constants.ApplicationURL);

//mapping to online easytable
var myTable = client.GetTable<MYTABLE>();

//Getting results from online azure sql database
var results = await myTable.ToListAsync();
```

A strange point is that I can populate my online database using the MobileServiceSQLiteStore. But if i re-run my app with synchronize online/offline code, I will read only the new inserted data. 
So, there is something preventing the local store initial filling, but no way to find anything helpfull.

Did you ever noticed this behaviour ?

I post this thread on the MSDN, but they sent me here :
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9c5db53f-8b64-4a00-85ac-26498a216e7e/never-getting-online-azure-data-using-mobileservicesqlitestore?forum=azuremobile&prof=required

Information about technical environment : 
VS2017, Xamarin.Forms, NetStandard2.0.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the origin of the problem.

Actually, the "ID" column name has to be named in lower case in the online azure SQL Server database. So Renaming it in the database and the JSon definition from "ID" to "id" solved the problem.

I hope it will help you